# Remove my last letter and I could become lethal

Tags: riddle, word

> My first 2 letters represents a male.
>   My first 3 letters represents a female.
>   My first 4 letters represents a great male.
>   My whole represents a great female.

Which word am I describing?

Comment: I welcome any downvote with an explanation of where and how to improve my posts.

Comment: you welcome downvotes? (it wasn't me btw)

Comment: Yeah. I had a downvote earlier on, I was just wondering if the downvoter can explain to me where can I improve.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Could it be:

> HEROINE, using HE, HER and HERO (and HEROIN from the title).

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same answer, so upvoted your one. +1

Answer (score 2):

My first 2 letters represents a male.

> HE

My first 3 letters represents a female.

> HER

My first 4 letters represents a great male.

> HERO

My whole represents a great female.

> HEROINE